# Am I screwed up forever once I logged into eduroam?

Tags: network-configuration

I use cyberghost VPN, Tor, and am tring to install Tails. I concern most about is, on campus I only have two options for network: Eduroam and guest WiFi.

I have several questions:

1. Guest wifi does not require password, privacy-wise, is guest wifi more private than  eduroam?
2. Once I logged into eduroam with my ID, does administrator copy my info such as Mac address?
3. Then, if they have my mac address, does it mean even if I use guest wifi, they still know it is me who is using it if they identify my mac address?
4. Is there anyway to set up network in my environment to achieve max anonymity?

Comment: ad 1) kind of... logging anywhere in (aka identifying yourself) always threats your privacy; although at the guest WiFi you may be more pseudonymous (if at all), than anonymous.

Comment: ad 2) the real true answer to this can only give the admin of *eduroam*. - and even he can lie or just make mistakes...

Comment: ad 3) for sure, this can happen. - but you can try to change/spoof your mac address, as Tails does.

Comment: ad 4) i don't understand this question, can you please elaborate it a bit more?